# Objective C integer comparison error

Tags: objective-c, lldb, comparison-operators

Can anyone explain to me these results out of Xcode/Objective C?  Surely there is no case in which -2 should ever test larger than 31.

```
(lldb) p dayOfMonth
(int) $37 = -2
(lldb) p (dayOfMonth > 31)
(bool) $38 = true
(lldb) p (dayOfMonth > (int)31)
(bool) $39 = true 
(lldb) p (dayOfMonth > (float)31) 
(bool) $40 = false
```

I've never seen straight-up wrong answers like that, and can't imagine how it could be being misinterpreted.  Like the debugger says, dayOfMonth is just an int.

Edit to add:  Here's the code that fails (with some irrelevant lines cut):

```
    NSRange monthdays = [self.calendar rangeOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit inUnit:NSMonthCalendarUnit forDate:self.displayedDate];
    int dayOfMonth = i+1-shift;  // negative days are at end of prev month; days higher than length of month are in next
    if (dayOfMonth < 1) cellView.dayLabel = prevMonthDays.length + dayOfMonth;
    if (dayOfMonth > monthdays.length) cellView.dayLabel = dayOfMonth - monthdays.length;
```

The second `if` evaluates true when dayOfMonth is negative.

Comment: Probably some odd binary thing.

Comment: For some reason, things are getting converted to unsigned types.  I don't see why in a quick scan of the docs.  I'm guessing it's a bug.  I get the same results here, but it works fine in GDB; can you use that instead?

Comment: It's not just in the debugger -- my compiled code is making the same error.

Comment: Can you post your actual code with any log results you have?

Comment: Please show your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed - it's a bug in the lldb IR interpreter.

Here's a link to the patch that fixes it: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/lldb-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130520/008569.html

Note that the new test case is exactly your problem:

```
+        self.expect("expression (int)-2",
+            startstr = "(int) $4 = -2")
+
+        self.expect("expression $4 > (int)31",
+            startstr = "(bool) $5 = false")
```

So that should keep things working for you in the future!

As far as your code goes, you do have a bug.  This condition:

```
if (dayOfMonth > monthdays.length)
```

Isn't doing what you want it to.  `dayOfMonth` is signed, and `monthdays.length` is unsigned.  That means `dayOfMonth` gets promoted to an unsigned type and the comparison goes bad.  You'll need a cast in there to clean things up:

```
if (dayOfMonth > (NSInteger)monthdays.length)
```

Comment: No problem - edited answer to explain the problem with your program as well.

Comment: Gah.  Surely C is just *wrong* to allow signed int to be silently "promoted" to unsigned.  I mean, clearly, that expression only tests as true because C decided to change one of the numbers on me.  But okay.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: But shouldn't I have gotten at least a warning about that invalid comparison?  Ack, I see Apple defaults GCC_WARN_SIGN_COMPARE to NO, jeez.  And Analyze doesn't pick it up either.