# Confusing LLDB output

Tags: objective-c, c, lldb

There's probably a hole in my C knowledge here, but I'm a little confused as to why this happening.

```
(lldb) p lineGroup
(NSInteger) $17 = -1
(lldb) p (lineGroup > 4)
(bool) $18 = true
(lldb) p (lineGroup < 0 )
(bool) $19 = false
(lldb) p (-1 < 0)
(bool) $20 = true
(lldb) p ((int)lineGroup < 0 )
(bool) $21 = false
(lldb) p ((int)lineGroup > 4)
(bool) $22 = true
(lldb)
```

The `lineGroup` variable is assigned as follows:

```
- (void)gotLineGroupInformation:(NSString *)lineGroupString
{
    NSInteger lineGroup = [lineGroupString integerValue];
    if(lineGroup >= 0)
    {
        // Always gets called
    }
    else
    {
        // Never gets called
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: What architecture have you compiled for? If 64-bit, NSInteger will be 64-bit but int will be 32-bit.

Comment: Is your question only about the apparently wrong debugger output? Or does your code not work as expected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C integer comparison error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725029/objective-c-integer-comparison-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lldb issue seem to be the exact same as in [Objective C integer comparison error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725029/objective-c-integer-comparison-error):

Carl Norum said in his response :

> Confirmed - it's a bug in the lldb IR interpreter.
>
> Here's a link to the patch that fixes it: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/lldb-commits/Week-of-Mon-20130520/008569.html

---

Concerning your code, I tried to reproduce the bug without succes with this test:

```
NSString *lineGroupString = @"-1";
NSInteger lineGroup = [lineGroupString integerValue];
if(lineGroup >= 0)
{
    NSLog(@"positive");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"negative"); // This log is correctly called every time
}
```

Maybe you should try to debug with `NSLog` for this one (in particular what is the value of `lineGroupString` right after entering the function ?).

Comment: Yes, this is a dup issue of the "Objective C integer comparison error".  lldb-179 in Xcode 4.6.x has the bug that Andy is reporting here; it is fixed in the top of tree lldb svn sources.  Any Xcode release past Xcode 4.6.x will include the fix.